# Is it possible to configure port number for Angular application?

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am building an angular application. The app will connect with server through httpClient. Each time when the app connect to the server, it uses different port. I want to configure the port number of this app, then every time when the app open the socket to communicate with the server, the app will always use the same port.

It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With latest version of angular-cli, you can change the port by editing angular.json file you now specify a port per "project"

```
projects": {
    "my-cool-project": {
        ... rest of project config omitted
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                    "port": 4500
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thank! Is it possible do that in ionic project?

Comment: Yes you can do it in the config as well as simply ionic serve -p 8002 --dev-logger-port 8103

Comment: thanks. Where is the config file for ionic? The app is for android and ios phone.

Comment: if you are using ionic 4, it should have angular.json file

Comment: I am using ionic 3. Is there a another way to update configuration file? I cannot find angular.json.

Comment: no there is no way other than starting the app with specific port.  Migrate to ionic 4